# Semi-installed ubuntu error

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation

So, I ran Ubuntu, used unetbootin and the operating system booted through the harddisk only.

I firstly chose to try it without installing, then clicked the <kbd>install</kbd> button.

Followed the instructions, made 3 partitions for `swap`, `/` , and `/home`. The installation began and my laptop's **battery died before completing the installation.**

Could anyone help me out to just revert back everything. When I try to install it again, it shows the operating system files in `/` and in `/home` directory but it didn't show me any option to load Ubuntu rather it just showed the unetbootin thing again on startup.

Comment: @Parashant: please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/660453/revisions)...  Thank you!  **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot from your live DVD/USB with the option "Try Ubuntu" again.
2. Use your favourite partition manager (Gnome Disks or GParted) to delete the previously created partitions.
3. Rerun the Ubuntu installation as if the previous installation didn't happen.

Comment: I'll try that and reply you back in a while. Thanks.

Comment: **David** That's the easiest, fastest and surest way!  +1
@GurJappanSingh: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd just reinstall from scratch, i'm guessing you've got no data to keep so that's the safest way.
It should give you an option to wipe the HardDisk when you renistall.

Comment: I have windows OS too which has vital data.